# create mongoose schema in correct way and insert document

Tags: mongodb, express

i am about to add list of countries from a github json file in mongodb using mongoose and expressjs, but its not working.

i am able to print countrieslist array in console log but unable to create collection in mongodb.

I think, i am doing something wrong with model schema.

here is my controller.

```
const { Country } = require('../models');
const addCountrytoDatabase = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
      
    try {
        const { data: countries } = await axios.get(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database/master/countries.json`);

        const countrieslist = [];
        countries.forEach(function (item) {

            arrcountries = {
                uniqueId: uuidv4(),
                countryId: item.id,
                name: item.name,
                iso3: item.iso3,
                iso2: item.iso2,
                numeric_code: item.numeric_code,
                phone_code: item.phone_code,
                capital: item.capital,
                currency: item.currency,
                currency_symbol: item.currency_symbol,
                tld: item.tld,
                native: item.native,
                region: item.region,
                subregion: item.subregion,
                timezones: item.timezones,
                latitude: item.latitude,
                longitude: item.longitude,
            }

            countrieslist.push(arrcountries);

        })

        const createdcountry = Country.insertMany(countrieslist);
        res.send(countrieslist)

    }

    catch (err) {
        res.send(err)
    }


});
```

here is the model.

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { toJSON, paginate } = require('./plugins');

    const countriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
        {
            uniqueId: { type: String, default: null },
            countryId: { type: String, default: null },
            name: { type: String, default: null },
            iso3: { type: String, default: null },
            iso2: { type: String, default: null },
            numeric_code: { type: String, default: null },
            phone_code: { type: String, default: null },
            capital: { type: String, default: null },
            currency: { type: String, default: null },
            currency_symbol: { type: String, default: null },
            tld: { type: String, default: null },
            native: { type: String, default: null },
            region: { type: String, default: null },
            subregion: { type: String, default: null },
            timezones: [{
                zoneName: {
                    type: String,
                    trim: true,
                    default: null
                },
                gmtOffset: {
                    type: String,
                    trim: true,
                    default: null
                },
                gmtOffsetName: {
                    type: String,
                    trim: true,
                    default: null
                },
                abbreviation: {
                    type: String,
                    trim: true,
                    default: null
                },
                tzName: {
                    type: String,
                    trim: true,
                    default: null
                },
            }],
            latitude: { type: Date, default: null },
            longitude: { type: String, default: null },
            emoji: { type: String, default: null },
            settings: {
                preferred_intl_destinations: [{
                    destinationName: { type:String, default: null },
                    destinationId: { type:String, default: null },
                    destinationImg: {
                          imageId: { type:String, default: null },
                          imageUrl: { type:String, default: null }
                     },
                }],
                preferred_domestic_destinations: [{
                    destinationName: { type: String, default: null },
                    destinationId: { type: String, default: null },
                    destinationImg: {
                        imageId: { type: String, default: null },
                        imageUrl: { type: String, default: null }
                    },
                }],
            }
        },
        {
            timestamps: true,
        }
    );
    
    
    countriesSchema.plugin(toJSON);
    countriesSchema.plugin(paginate);
    
    
    const Country = mongoose.model('ttc_Countries', countriesSchema);
    
    
    module.exports = Country;
```

this is the format of document that i want to create.

```
[{
    "uniqueId": "47bf28c8-383a-4ec9-8791-cf57f4577de2",
    "countryId": 14,
    "name": "Australia",
    "iso3": "AUS",
    "iso2": "AU",
    "numeric_code": "036",
    "phone_code": "61",
    "capital": "Canberra",
    "currency": "AUD",
    "currency_symbol": "$",
    "tld": ".au",
    "native": "Australia",
    "region": "Oceania",
    "subregion": "Australia and New Zealand",
    "timezones": [
        {
            "zoneName": "Antarctica/Macquarie",
            "gmtOffset": 39600,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+11:00",
            "abbreviation": "MIST",
            "tzName": "Macquarie Island Station Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Adelaide",
            "gmtOffset": 37800,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+10:30",
            "abbreviation": "ACDT",
            "tzName": "Australian Central Daylight Saving Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Brisbane",
            "gmtOffset": 36000,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+10:00",
            "abbreviation": "AEST",
            "tzName": "Australian Eastern Standard Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Broken_Hill",
            "gmtOffset": 37800,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+10:30",
            "abbreviation": "ACDT",
            "tzName": "Australian Central Daylight Saving Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Currie",
            "gmtOffset": 39600,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+11:00",
            "abbreviation": "AEDT",
            "tzName": "Australian Eastern Daylight Saving Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Darwin",
            "gmtOffset": 34200,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+09:30",
            "abbreviation": "ACST",
            "tzName": "Australian Central Standard Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Eucla",
            "gmtOffset": 31500,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+08:45",
            "abbreviation": "ACWST",
            "tzName": "Australian Central Western Standard Time (Unofficial)"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Hobart",
            "gmtOffset": 39600,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+11:00",
            "abbreviation": "AEDT",
            "tzName": "Australian Eastern Daylight Saving Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Lindeman",
            "gmtOffset": 36000,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+10:00",
            "abbreviation": "AEST",
            "tzName": "Australian Eastern Standard Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Lord_Howe",
            "gmtOffset": 39600,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+11:00",
            "abbreviation": "LHST",
            "tzName": "Lord Howe Summer Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Melbourne",
            "gmtOffset": 39600,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+11:00",
            "abbreviation": "AEDT",
            "tzName": "Australian Eastern Daylight Saving Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Perth",
            "gmtOffset": 28800,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+08:00",
            "abbreviation": "AWST",
            "tzName": "Australian Western Standard Time"
        },
        {
            "zoneName": "Australia/Sydney",
            "gmtOffset": 39600,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+11:00",
            "abbreviation": "AEDT",
            "tzName": "Australian Eastern Daylight Saving Time"
        }
    ],
    "latitude": "-27.00000000",
    "longitude": "133.00000000"
},
{
    "uniqueId": "d3244958-77d6-4b0d-9f45-400a918b2887",
    "countryId": 15,
    "name": "Austria",
    "iso3": "AUT",
    "iso2": "AT",
    "numeric_code": "040",
    "phone_code": "43",
    "capital": "Vienna",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "currency_symbol": "€",
    "tld": ".at",
    "native": "Österreich",
    "region": "Europe",
    "subregion": "Western Europe",
    "timezones": [
        {
            "zoneName": "Europe/Vienna",
            "gmtOffset": 3600,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+01:00",
            "abbreviation": "CET",
            "tzName": "Central European Time"
        }
    ],
    "latitude": "47.33333333",
    "longitude": "13.33333333"
},
{
    "uniqueId": "6738bab1-b29c-40d7-89b1-6db824a5a32d",
    "countryId": 16,
    "name": "Azerbaijan",
    "iso3": "AZE",
    "iso2": "AZ",
    "numeric_code": "031",
    "phone_code": "994",
    "capital": "Baku",
    "currency": "AZN",
    "currency_symbol": "m",
    "tld": ".az",
    "native": "Azərbaycan",
    "region": "Asia",
    "subregion": "Western Asia",
    "timezones": [
        {
            "zoneName": "Asia/Baku",
            "gmtOffset": 14400,
            "gmtOffsetName": "UTC+04:00",
            "abbreviation": "AZT",
            "tzName": "Azerbaijan Time"
        }
    ],
    "latitude": "40.50000000",
    "longitude": "47.50000000"
},.....]
```

Comment: when you say "unable to create colleciton", what exactly do you mean? Is there some error/exception or it fails silently?

Comment: in postman, it gives 200 response. but nothing is being created in mongodb. there is no error at all.